# How to change the state inside a backgroundworker?

Tags: c#-4.0, backgroundworker

I'm developing an application in C# (vs 2015) and I've run into a problem.

I'm running a backgroundWorker that receives a continuous stream of images. I need to stop or restart this stream at the click of a button but I don't know how to change the internal state of the backgroundWorker. I can pass initial parameters to the backgroundWorker, but how do I change one of those internal parameters after the backgroundWorker has been asynchronously run?

Many thanks for your help.
Steve

Comment: Typically the BackgroundWorker() handlers are within the Form class itself, so they can see the same **Form level scoped variables** that a Button Click() handler could see.  Declare a variable at Form level and periodically check it from within your DoWork() handler.  Alternatively, just call [BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync(v=vs.110).aspx) and within your DoWork() handler periodically check the **BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending** flag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do keep track of the restarting yourself. For example with a bool.

```
private bool _restart = false;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _restart = true;
    _backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (_backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
    {
        return;
    }
    // do work
}

private void backgroundWorker_WorkComplete(object sender, eventargs e)  //no ide to hand not sure on name/args
{
    if (_restart)
    {
        _restart = false;
        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```